# Why are the buttons in this program not clickable?

Tags: swift, xcode

I've created a UI for my settings that allows the user to click image buttons, which changes the screen. However, clicking on the images does nothing in simulation/preview. It should be displaying different pages for each icon using navigation link. Any suggestions?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsPageUI: View {
    
    @StateObject var SettingsModel: settingsvm = settingsvm()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack() {
                NavigationLink(destination: SleepUI().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $SettingsModel.showSleepUI, label: { EmptyView() })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CoffeeUI().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $SettingsModel.showCoffeeUI, label: { EmptyView() })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseUI().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $SettingsModel.showExerciseUI, label: { EmptyView() })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SugarUI().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $SettingsModel.showSugarUI, label: { EmptyView() })
                
                
                VStack() {
                    HStack(alignment:.top) {
                        Button {
                            SettingsModel.showSleepUI = true
                        } label: {
                            Image("Sleep")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 100)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            SettingsModel.showCoffeeUI = true
                        }) {
                            Image("Coffee")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 80)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            SettingsModel.showExerciseUI = true
                        }) {
                            Image("Exercise")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            SettingsModel.showSugarUI = true
                        }) {
                            Image("Sugar")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Please Click an Icon to edit settings.")
                        .frame(width:500,height:750)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ZStack` puts everything one on top of the other. The `View` that contains a single `Text` which is not clickable is on top

Comment: @loremipsum How could I fix this?

Comment: 1. Put the `Text` inside the `VStack` is one option. 2. Get rid of the `ZStack` and put the  `NavigationLink`s in the `.background`. 3. Use the links directly instead of buttons. There are many options it just depends on what you want it to look like, your preferences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `EmptyView()` with the content.

For example:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: SleepUI().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $SettingsModel.showSleepUI, label: {
    Button {
        SettingsModel.showSleepUI = true
    } label: {
        Image("Sleep")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
})
```